# Error while running bash command in python using subprocess: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, bash, command-line

I am trying to execute the following bash command in python using the subprocess python package but its throwing me an error.

the bashCommand variable in the following code stores the bash command i'm trying to execute

```py
def desc_calc():
    bashCommand = "java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ./PaDEL-Descriptor/PaDEL-Descriptor.jar -removesalt -standardizenitro -fingerprints -descriptortypes ./PaDEL-Descriptor/PubchemFingerprinter.xml -dir ./ -file descriptors_output.csv"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

upon running the code, i get the following error:

```
2023-01-25 17:27:06.101 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oo_wa\.conda\envs\streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 563, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\oo_wa\OneDrive\Desktop\BUSI_Dashboard\pages\2_Drug Discovery.py", line 82, in <module>
    desc_calc()
  File "C:\Users\oo_wa\OneDrive\Desktop\BUSI_Dashboard\pages\2_Drug Discovery.py", line 44, in desc_calc
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\oo_wa\.conda\envs\streamlit\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\oo_wa\.conda\envs\streamlit\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Is `java` in `PATH`?

Comment: @Armali not sure. i will check it out. thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Armali i just added `java` to `PATH` but it doesn't change anything. i still get the same error.

Comment: You mean, you added the directory containing `java.exe`, don't you?

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but maybe specifying explicitly `java.exe` instead of `java` could help.

Comment: yes, i added this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin` to the system path. @Armali

Comment: @qouify replacing `java` with `jave.exe` fixed it. thanks a lot :)